# UPDATE query not change data in MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm writing an application in express.js. I'm using the "mysql" add-on (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). I am sending an UPDATE query. The server returns me:

```
{"fieldCount": 0, "affectedRows": 1, "insertId": 0, "serverStatus": 2, "warningCount": 0, 
"message": "(Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0", " protocol41 ": true," changedRows ": 0}
```

I copy the query to phpMyAdmin and perform it correctly - it changes the data in the database.
Where do I make a mistake?

I send: "UPDATE `measurements` SET `sugar_level` = '429', `insulin_dose` = '200', `hour_of_measurement` = '20', `date_of_measurement` = '2019-07-29'
 WHERE `measurements`.`ID` = '14'" Query: INSERT INTO, DELETE FROM, SELECT working fine

Comment: What is the query you're sending?

Comment: Try writing a different update statement to a different table. See if you can create a new table. A new table that you have created possibly. This is to try and narrow down if it is a permissions issue (ie you only have read only access to that database). Check if it affects only one table/database/etc

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the UPDATE statement found one row that satisfied the conditions in the WHERE clause. That seems reasonable if the condition is an equality on the primary key or unique key columns, for example

```
 UPDATE ... WHERE t.id = ?
```

If all of the values assigned to columns match the values already stored, then MySQL will report that the row is not changed. It's reasonable for a query like this

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol = mycol
```

to match all rows in the table, and to change zero rows.

Note that the value returned for affectedRows is the value of matchedRows.

It's reasonable for matchedRows to have a different value than changedRows.

NOTE: A BEFORE UPDATE trigger might affect the NEW.mycol value, so in that case, its reasonable to get a lot of rows changed.

The serverStatus value of 2 is telling us that autocommit is enabled.

---

Bottom line: the response from MySQL server is what we expect if we were to run a query

```
 UPDATE mytable SET mycol = mycol WHERE id = ?
```

Where we are finding exactly one row in the table that matches the condition, but after the assignment(s) are performed, the resulting row is identical to the row at the start of the statement i.e. there was no actual "change" made to the row.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

```
UPDATE measurements 
   SET sugar_level         = '429'
     , insulin_dose        = '200'
     , hour_of_measurement = '20'
     , date_of_measurement = '2019-07-29'
 WHERE measurements.ID = '14'
```

Assuming that there is one row in the table with ID value of 14, and assuming no BEFORE UPDATE trigger on the table mucks with a value being assigned to a column

Then it's perfectly reasonable for the execution of this statement to "match" one row and "change" zero rows. In particular, after a second execution.  If we were to actually change one of the values, say change sugar_level to '430', then we would expect to see a changed row.

---

I strongly suspect that MySQL is operating per the specification (i.e. "perform correctly").

(It's not at clear why OP considers the result returned as incorrect, or believes the operation performed incorrectly.)

Comment: we're just guessing. one possibility is that the code (which is not provided, so we can't tell, we're just making guesses, which is *not* an efficient way to debug programs) maybe the SQL statement is being executed twice. The first time, it's making a change, the second time, there are no changes to make. Maybe what we're seeing here is just the result from the second execution. Again, without seeing some actual code, an actual test that we can reproduce, we're just flinging dung at the wall to see what sticks.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @wachcio: do not post code related to the *question* as a comment on an answer. There is an *edit* button on the question. Presumably, the links posted as comments here are code that is exhibiting the behavior described in the question. This information belongs in the *question*. Don't *hide* this information in comments that StackOverflow question readers may not read.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. I've set the v-model wrong and the data to change was the same as the old one